# Creating an executable jar

Tags: java, jar

I had written a program:

```
public class SystemShutdown {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -s -t 2700");
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

I'd compiled and kept the `.class` file separate.

Now, I'd write a manifest file as:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: SystemShutdown
```

And saved with the name `MANIFEST.MF`

I'd put both (the `.class` file and the `MANIFEST.MF` file) in same directory.

Now I want to create an `Executable Jar` file. For that I'd done:

```
jar cvfm MyJar.jar *.*
```

A jar file is created after that.
But when I tries to execute it displays a message `Java Exception occured`.

Can anybody help me out?
I want to execute this program on the users double click.

Beside of the above scratch can anybody tell me the exact steps to be followed to create an executable jar?

I'm using `Windows7 32bit` and `jdk7`

Comment: Any particular Java Exception? A message would be helpful; A stack trace even more so.  The manifest might be a culprit here.

Comment: @Captain: no particular exception. There is an error message `Java Exception occured`

Comment: Even when you run it in a console window? What IDE are you using? Are you notepadding this?

Comment: It would be helpful if your code didn't just swallow all exceptions, of course...

Comment: @Captain: No, there is no error or exception when I simply execute the program without creating a jar

Comment: Yes, please do e.printStackTrace(); in the catch clause. Indulge us with this =)

Comment: Edit your question to include the output.

Comment: @Captain: there is no output of my program. But the thing I wanted to do is that, after `10seconds` my program executes a `command` to `shutdown` my computer. When the program is executed, after `10seconds` it shows a notification for system shutdown.

Comment: I was referring to the output of e.printStackTrace()

Comment: What happens when you do "start TheJarFile.jar" on the command line? I'm assuming you are on a windows system.

Comment: @Mohammad Jon showed you the exact steps to create a jar. Did you try those steps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `m` option of the command line for `jar` says you'll provide the manifest file as the following parameter (in this case, after the jar file itself). So I suspect you want:

```
jar cvfm MyJar.jar MANIFEST.MF SystemShutdown.class
```

See the [jar tool documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) for more details.

EDIT: I've just tried this and it works fine. Code:

```
// In Test.java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

// Manifest in MANIFEST.MF:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Test
```

Command line and output:

```
javac Test.java
jar cvfm test.jar MANIFEST.MF Test.class
java -jar test.jar
Hello
```

Note that if you don't have a line terminator at the end of the `Main-Class` line in the manifest, that will cause an error, but it's somewhat better specified:

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from test.jar
```

Comment: still the problem is as it is

Comment: @Mohammad: Well I just tried exactly the same thing, and it worked fine. If it's failing for you, perhaps it's a JRE problem? What platform are you on? Have you tried running a similar test app which *doesn't* try to shut the machine down?

Comment: did you get your `jar` executed?

Comment: Yes That is Jon's `java -jar test.jar` command on  the next to last line in the penultimate code segment.

Comment: @Mohammad: How are you trying to execute this? As I asked before, what platform are you on What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @Mohammad No I guess we would expect a permissions problem rather.

Comment: @Jon: i'm using `jdk7` on `Windows7` OS. When the `jar` file is created then I simply double-clicks on that, but it says `A Java Exception has Occured.` with entitled `Java Virtual Machine Launcher` But past few days I'd downloaded an executable `jar` file which executes well.

Comment: @Mohammad: Right, so try running it from the command line like I have. You may get more information that way.

Comment: @Jon I'm not that familiar with Windows (console), but wouldn't `start TheJar.jar` be more like a double click?

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: Quite possibly - I suspect it won't attach to the console as `java -jar jarfile.jar` will, which is why I suggested using `java` directly... we *want* more information.

Comment: @jon: when i'm trying `java -jar MyJar.jar` there is nullpointerException

Comment: @Mohammad: Well there we go. More information. Please show the full stack trace of the NullPointerException.

Comment: @jon: the stack trace is: `sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJUar(Unknown Source)` and `sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)`

Comment: @Mohammad how did you start that jar? And please edit your question to add this info.

Comment: @Captain: please tell me how to create an executable jar. Tell me the steps what you follows!!! I also wanted to know about `META-INF` folder

Comment: @Mohammad: That sounds very odd indeed... I've just tried it again at home and it's worked fine here too...

Comment: @Mohammad: My answer shows the exact steps necessary to create and execute a jar file. If it's not working for you, that suggests there's something wrong with your environment.

Comment: @Mohammad You wont get better answers from me than from Jon. Jon provided his answer. It would be like asking Newton about General relativity when Albert is sitting right next to you. Manual tip of the hat to Jon.

Comment: @Mohammad: So what did you change?

Comment: @Jon: previously I'm using jdk7 but don't know what went wrong. now I'd created jar using jdk6

Comment: @Jon: can you please tell me how can i change the icon of an executable jar?

Comment: @Mohammad: I'm afraid I don't know. I suggest you ask a new question - it's likely to be OS-specific.

Comment: @Jon: I want to minimize my `JFrame` to the `system tray icon` in `windows`. Do you have any answer post it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461477/move-a-jframe-to-tray-on-minimize

Comment: @Mohammad: Please don't just keep adding comments with extra questions which are irrelevant to this one. If I see a question I can answer, I'll do so - if *everyone* kept drawing my attention to their question, I'd have far too many comments to read.