# hiding and showing java desktop app with action listener

Tags: java, swing, jsr296

I have a java desktop app I made writing with netbeans. 
What I did is to listen to windows close and minimize to the tray.
I added to myApp.java a listener on startup method that listen to window close and then hide the myAppView.

The thing I created a icontray in taskbar and I want to open same frame I had before.
I declared the appView as global variable but can do show(myapp) cause it says its static.
any idea how to get this to work?

```
public class myApp extends SingleFrameApplication {
    private myAppView mainv;


    @Override protected void startup() {
        mainv=new myAppView(this);
        show(mainv);
        addExitListener(new ExitListener() {

           public boolean canExit( EventObject event ) {
              systray();
              hide(mainv);

              return false;
           }

        public void willExit( EventObject arg0 ) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    });
}

/**
 * This method is to initialize the specified window by injecting resources.
 * Windows shown in our application come fully initialized from the GUI
 * builder, so this additional configuration is not needed.
 */
@Override protected void configureWindow(java.awt.Window root) {

}

/**
 * A convenient static getter for the application instance.
 * @return the instance of find4me
 */
public static myApp getApplication() {
    return Application.getInstance(myApp.class);
}

/**
 * Main method launching the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(myApp.class, args);
}
```

Comment: Hopefully this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8909348/1057230) by @MohammedFaisal will surely help you in your endeavour :-)

Comment: what im hiding is not a frame its the mainView

Comment: It's tough to understand, exactly what this `mainView` is meant to do, May you point an [Short Compilable form](http://sscce.org/) of your code, that will be much appreciated.

Comment: So what does show and hide do?  What is mainView?  There isn't enough info to really be able to help