# JPanel minimize to system-tray?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, system-tray

I am in the making of a small Java program and I was wondering how, if at all, I could make it so that if I was to press the minimize button on my `JPanel` it would not minimize into the taskbar but into the system-tray.

Could anyone please post the code for that? 
Thanks!

Comment: `JPanel`s don't have minimize buttons

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461477/how-to-hide-a-jframe-in-system-tray-of-taskbar