# Close window - but don't stop program - JAVA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, dispose

In my program it opens a window if an action is happened. After I have filled out information in this window, and entered a button, the window dispose().

The window is picked up in a program outside my main program, but when I close this window, my main program stops. How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can set the `defalaultCloseOperation` property of the second frame to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` or  `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`
2. Don't even use two frames. Use a modal `JDialog` instead for a secondary frame. See more at [How to Use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). Read more about [Modality](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/modality-137604.html). And for a good read, see [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/2587435)
3. Forget about number 1. and go straight to 2.

Answer (score 3):

If using JFrame or extending it you can use [setDefaultCloseOperation()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) method like:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
// or
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dispose` command is from the AWT Bundle, and this may cause problems, as you are attempting to "close" a swing window with an AWT command.

You can close the window with this command:

```
windowName.setVisable(false);
```

`windowName` is the name of the object representing the window. If you are extending a class, and have no object, you can use `this`

More Information on the Dispose Method:
"In general java.awt.Window.dispose() is used on a GUI component that is
a subclass of Window, in order for that specific GUI Window object (and
its children) to properly release and destroy native UI resources (such
as the screen). Garbage collection (and the eventual exiting of the
entire VM) may happen as a result of dispose(), but is not directly
connected with the dispose() call itself." *From: https://www.java.net/node/684412*

Comment: but after i have closed the window by either pressing close button(X) or one of the three buttons in the window, i have typed in the command dispose(). I want to dispose the window, but to continue the main program.

Comment: Why is that necessary?

Comment: Java's Garbage Collection should automatically dispose of the lightweight Swing components after they are not in use.

Comment: because after the operator of the program have typed in the data, the window is not necessary any more.

Comment: So once the window closes, is there a problem with letting the Java VM's Automatic Reference Counting (Garbage Collection) take care of managing the disposal?

Answer (score 0):

```
windowName.setVisable(false);
```

doesn't seems to be a good choice. What if user want to exit the program?

check this question - [How to hide a JFrame in system tray of taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461477/how-to-hide-a-jframe-in-system-tray-of-taskbar)