# When closing the JFrame main method execution should not be stopped

Tags: java

In java swing main method execution should not be stopped once the JFrame is closed using EXIT_ON_CLOSE or DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close window - but don't stop program - JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739578/close-window-but-dont-stop-program-java)

Comment: No, I have only one frame and if I closed it through that close sign then I want the further execution of my main method. Which is not clarified here I guess.